# Return Variable From Function

Tags: javascript, json

I am a beginner in JS and I have difficulty understanding why the output of my var is "Undefined." My JS runs a GET to download a JSON file and with a function, I am trying to read the file and return the first line:

```
invest.stock('APPLE', function (err, data) {
      if (err) { console.log('ERROR', err); return; }
      var APPLE_price = data.order[0]['price'];
      console.log(APPLE_price); //until here works fine
});
    console.log(APPLE_price); //output "Undefined" var
```

I tried declare the var previously, I created a statement to wait the var (because was a async function) but nothing works.

Comment: Look at javascript variable scope.

Comment: @Felipe, I added answer, Hope it will help you to understand the function level scope of the variable in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the variable outside of the function first:

```
var APPLE_price;
invest.stock('APPLE', function (err, data) {
  if (err) { console.log('ERROR', err); return; }
  APPLE_price = data.order[0].price;
  console.log(APPLE_price); //until here works fine
});
setTimeout(() => console.log(APPLE_price), 2000);
```

But it would be far more elegant to use a callback or a Promise:

```
function getApplePrice() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    invest.stock('APPLE', function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
        return;
      }
      resolve(data.order[0].price);
    });
  });
}
getApplePrice().then(applePrice => {
  console.log('applePrice is ' + applePrice);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

your problem here is the variable scoop it's called the local scoop, you can't use

`var APPLE_price` outside  the function

you can find a reference here for javascript scoops [JavaScript Scopes](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)
for that.In this situation, you can declare the variable outside the function

```
var Name = " john";

function myFunction() {

// code here can use Name 

 }
// code here can use Name
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is scope.

Since the scope of `APPLE_PRICE` is limited to the function it is in you cannot access it outside the function. But best to read some tutorials on variable scoping in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

> var APPLE_price = data.order[0]['price'];

Here, `APPLE_price` is a Local variable (Function-level scope). As it is declared within a function. Hence, only accessible within that function or by functions inside that function.

If you want access `APPLE_price` outside of a function you need to declare it outside the function.

```
var APPLE_price;
invest.stock('APPLE', function (err, data) {
      if (err) { console.log('ERROR', err); return; }
      APPLE_price = data.order[0]['price'];
      console.log(APPLE_price); // value of data.order[0]['price']
});
    console.log(APPLE_price); // value of APPLE_price under invest.stock function.
```